# Controls in DataGrid WPF with dynamic columns

Tags: datagrid, datatable

I need to put a stackpanel inside the table cell but if i did my logic like this....

DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();

sp.Height = 18;

sp.Width = 60;

sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

Button btn = new Button();

btn.Width = 10;

btn.Height = 10;

sp.Children.Add(btn);

Label bt = new Label();

bt.Content = "test";

bt.Margin = new Thickness(0, -3, 0, 0);

sp.Children.Add(bt);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("hello");

dt.Columns.Add(dc);

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

dr[0] = sp; dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dg.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

l1.Content = dg;

it is showing "System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel" in the cell..... how to get a StackPanel(with multiple Controls) in side the GridView cell

Answer (score 0):

You should create custom template for your grid cells. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/19/wpf-datagrid-stock-and-template-columns.aspx).